# How to skip the the first lag N days in ARIMA model (python)?

Tags: python, data-structures, time-series, lag, arima

I have data containing daily sales of 21 weeks (17 weeks of training data, 4 weeks of validation data), and want to forecast daily sales for the next week, e.g. standing on the Monday of week 10, I want to use the data of week 1-9 to predict daily sales of week 11 in python.

Since there is missing 1-2 weeks of data before the target date (for week 11 Mon, I miss lag 1-7, for week 11 Sun, I miss lag 1-13), how should I construct the independent variables, data structure or config arima model, so that in training data it can reflect the missing dates and won't take the recent lags as input?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I see two possibilities for this here.

1. I assume you are using statsmodels ARIMA class. You can specify which lags ARIMA is supposed to use when defining the order. E.g., if you give `order=(4,0,0)` it will use the last four lags for the autoregression component. If you give `order=([1,0,1,1],0,0)` it will only use the last, third and fourth last lags while ignoring the second last. In the `[]` you can define which lags to use with a 1 and which to ignore with a 0 for the specific component.
2. You could use imputing to fill the missing values. There are many ways to do this and you need to find a good one for your usecase, for starters you can have a look here: https://machinelearningmastery.com/statistical-imputation-for-missing-values-in-machine-learning/

I do not know your usecase, but I would suggest the second way.